# SVG circle with diameter = odd number

Tags: svg, geometry

I would like to draw a circle with it's diameter being an odd number (7px), so I can draw a 1px line exactly through the center of the circle.

```
<svg width="600" height="600"> 
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3.5" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Strangely, the diameter is always even, no matter what is `r` value.

[image: svg circle, odd diameter value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the `cx` and `cy` coordinates by `.5`:

```
<svg width="600" height="600"> 
    <circle cx="30.5" cy="30.5" r="3.5" fill="red" />
</svg>
```